# react-router, server sided rendering with Koa/Express. How to import/export compiled routes

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-router

My React app imports images sass and fonts and other modules/plugins which all should be compiled before going in production by Webpack.

How can I render server sided and import the routes from from the compiled React app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a second Webpack config which will compile the server sided JS root file does the trick.

This starter kit is very barebones and gives a clear view of what needs to be done:
https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit